# In Selenium for Python, is it possible to only execute a function if the program detects you're on a specific webpage?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data off the [Crunchbase website](https://www.crunchbase.com). To access [the data](https://www.crunchbase.com/discover/saved/boca-startups/1cde2234-09c1-42ce-a18d-dda4d867b70c) in full, I have to log in first. I've set the program up to type in my username and password, but for some reason it is very difficult to press the "log in" button. Is there a way with selenium to only execute my data-scraping function when the program detects I'm on a certain webpage?

Comment: what difficulty you face for click on the login button?

Comment: So, your problem is to click on login button or to detect the page you are?

Comment: It's difficult to identify the login button, so I'd rather just input it manually. My problem is to determine which page I'm on.

Comment: By which page you are, you mean URL or the content of page?